# How can i get all rows from left side and only matched rows in right side table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables..i needs to get all rows from left side table but only the matched rows from right side table..

```
Left table: tbl_BT

BT_Id   Name    
 1       A
 2       B
 3       C
 4       D
 5       E
```

Right table : tbl_Rc

```
Rc_ID   Country   BT_Id
 1       Con1      1
 2       Con2      2
 3       Con3      5
```

Result Table :

```
BT_Id   Name  Rc_Id   Country
 1       A     1       Con1
 2       B     2       Con2
 3       C     -        -
 4       D     -        -
 5       E     3       Con3
```

Please help me to get this.

Comment: use left join between first and second table

Comment: when i use left join it was return only the values which presents in table2.

Comment: if you have tables like you show it here than it will work, check if you have written left join wrong

Comment: BTW:these are not my original tables..but still is not working my real tables..any way thanks for your comment.

Comment: show the code and maybe we can help you

Answer (score 1):

So what you need is a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT bt.BT_Id as BT_Id,bt.Name as Name ,
  IFNULL(rc.Rc_ID,"-") as Rc_Id,IFNULL(rc.Country,"-") as Country
FROM tbl_BT bt LEFT JOIN tbl_Rc rc 
ON bt.BT_Id=rc.BT_Id
```

`IFNULL()` is in case you have nulls on right table so you have `-` shown instead of `null`

Comment: `select *` will give all columns from both tables, but OP asks for only *some* of the columns

Comment: meanwhile i changed it

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
SELECT tbl_BT.BT_Id,Name,Rc_Id,Country from tbl_BT 
left join tbl_Rc on tbl_BT.BT_Id = tbl_Rc.BT_Id
```

Comment: left join was not return the needed output..its just has return only the three records which was present in tbl2.

Comment: @user10489 I seriously doubt that. Are you *sure* you coded `on` and not `where`?

Comment: i gave it the sample code only..but my original tables were not return the needed result..thank you for your comment.